# on our prod server we have a UI which has a search engine

Tags: linux, centos-7

we recently encountered high CPU usage for 2 applications(i.e one app used 900%cpu and second app used 700% cpu) in our prod server and also noticed high load average of 22, 17, 10 so we have increased CPU resources from 12 to 24 cores. now we still see a significantly high load avg i.e **17 15 10** but over all CPU usage is very low(i.e 4%/).

Note: 1. when we have high load avg on our Prod server our UI search engine takes very long time to fetch requested information.
2. **we also encountered I/O Speed(specifically disk write speed) is being drastically reduced from 700MB/s to 4.8MB/s**. and we frequently see below error when we have high load avg.

Error: Message from syslogd@nabu at Nov 2 19:06:21 ... kernel:NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 22s! [kworker/0:2:17931]

Message from syslogd@nabu at Nov 2 19:06:49 ... kernel:NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 22s! [kworker/0:2:17931]

Message from syslogd@nabu at Nov 2 19:07:18 ... kernel:NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 22s! [kworker/0:2:17931]

Assistance here would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked your disk is not dying?  High load values indicate the number of processes waiting, which likely indicates a disk bottleneck.  You can run "vmstat -5" to look at where the bottleneck is occuring.

Comment: we have ran above said vmstat 5 command but unble to figure out any.
we donot have load avg now. server is quite healthy now.
do you recommand us to check in our peak usage time?? then pls lets know what parameters to consider in vmstat command.

Below is current out put of vmstat 5

procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 1  0      0 62171048   9396 295216    0    0     1     2    2    5  1  1 98  0  0

Comment: Use  sar and post the output for us, showing the high usage. Soft lockups should be logged as well in /var/log/messages

Comment: below is Sar output for load avg.

Comment: 05:40:53  IST        34       594     22.42     16.10      7.70         0
05:50:38  IST        21       567     11.16     16.11     12.36         0
06:00:26  IST         7       571     11.76      9.29     10.38         0

Comment: please assist only we see spike in load avg not in cpu resource now. we tried to increase disk read/write by increasing default values in ulimit. but issue is the same.